# Перечисления в пхп

Tags: php

Есть такая конструкция:

```
if ($cn !== "RU") {
    $url=$moder; 
    $reason="Страна не Россия";
}

 else {
    if ($url!==$moder) { 
        $url=$user; 
    } 
}
```

как мне добавить доп страны? Например US

Если тупо скопировать и вставить последовательно, но с изменением RU на US, работать перестает:

```
if ($cn !== "RU") {
    $url=$moder; 
    $reason="Страна не Россия";
}

 else {
    if ($url!==$moder) { 
        $url=$user; 
    } 
}
if ($cn !== "US") {
    $url=$moder; 
    $reason="Страна не Россия";
}

 else {
    if ($url!==$moder) { 
        $url=$user; 
    } 
}
```

Может быть можно как-то сделать перечисление стран в этом месте: `if ($cn !== "US")`   ?
Например `if ($cn !== "US","RU")`

Но в таком виде тоже ошибку выдает...
Как правильно сделать перечисления стран?

Comment: `!in_array($cn, ['ru', 'us'])`

Comment: а можно в контексте моего кода подсказать куда это вставить ? А то я от пхп очень далек

Comment: Поэтому нужно сначала выучить пых, а потом задавать вопросы. Если вы не хотите этого делать, обратитесь на сайт фриланса. Там за вас всё сделают

Comment: `!in_array($cn, ['ru', 'us']) {
    $url=$moder; 
    $reason="Страна не Россия";
}

 else {
    if ($url!==$moder) { 
        $url=$user; 
    } 
}`

@teran, заменил строку с if на "ваш" код, пишет синтакс еррор

Comment: я ваш код не понял вообще, так что в контексте не подскажу

Comment: Что значит "работать перестает"?

Comment: @Эникейщик
это клоака, перестает делать редиректы. В $moder указан домен для модераторов, а в $user - для юзеров соответственно

@Дмитрий
Я дико извиняюь, строкой выше задается параметр для $cn
`$cn = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip);`
а в вашем примере он отсутствует совсем

Comment: Вы можете понятнее выражаться? Что ожидаете, что происходит? Почитайте в справке как задавать вопросы.

Comment: @Эникейщик
суть в том что так:
`if ($cn !== "RU") {
    $url=$moder; 
    $reason="Страна не Россия";
}

 else {
    if ($url!==$moder) { 
        $url=$user; 
    } 
}
if ($cn !== "US") {
    $url=$moder; 
    $reason="Страна не Россия";
}

 else {
    if ($url!==$moder) { 
        $url=$user; 
    } 
}`

сделать не получается. Т.е. тупо копировать код и поменять страну в `if ($cn !== "RU") `  Так и не понял как в комментах сделать код НЕ в одну строку.
  Тупо перестают работать редиректы. А если делать так:
`if ($cn !== "US","RU")`

то вообще синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: Вы можете понятнее выражаться? Какие редиректы? Где в вопросе хоть слово о редиректах? Исправьте вопрос, чтобы в нем содержалась вся необходимая для понимания информация.

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю зачем это нужно, но примерно так:

```
$array = ['RU', 'US'];
foreach ($array as $item):
    if ($item !== "RU"){
        $url = $moder;
        $reason = "Страна не Россия";
    }
    elseif ($url !== $moder) {
        $url = $user;
    }
endforeach;
```